# Switch arguments of an "mv" command

Tags: command-line, mv

If you type

```
mv a.txt b.txt
```

and then realise you made a mistake, instead of retyping the line and switching the arguments, does something like the following exist:

```
mv a.txt b.txt --reverse
```

Comment: A long long time ago a UNIX admin taught me a trick to avoid mv mishaps. Don’t - instead cp, verify and rm the original…

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any such argument in GNU `mv`, but if you're using bash, [readline can help you](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Killing):

> `shell-transpose-words` (`M-C-t`)
>
> Drag the word before point past the word after point, moving point past that word as well. If the insertion point is at the end of the
> line, this transposes the last two words on the line. Word boundaries
> are the same as `shell-forward-word` and `shell-backward-word`.

So with:

```
$ mv bar/baz\ foo foo\ bar/baz
                              ^ cursor here
```

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) results in:

```
$ mv foo\ bar/baz bar/baz\ foo
                              ^ cursor here
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't. However, you may be able to use the text editing features of your shell to save on keystrokes. In the following, the `^` shall indicate the cursor position.

### Example: Bash

- Start situation:

  ```
  mv a.txt b.txt
                ^
  ```
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

  ```
  mv a.txt 
           ^
  ```

  The "last word" (`b.txt`) is cut and stored in the internal buffer.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> until the cursor is in front of `a.txt`

  ```
  mv a.txt
     ^
  ```
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

  ```
  mv b.txta.txt
          ^
  ```

  to paste the last deleted word.
- Insert a single space

It is still cumbersome, but somewhat faster. **Notice** that if your terminal emulator swallows any of these keystrokes, you are out of luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script called for example `unmv` that you put anywhere in your `$PATH` (for example in `/usr/local/bin`):

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "$2" "$1"
```

Then after you accidentally type `mv a.txt b.txt`, you can just type `unmv a.txt b.txt` to revert the change.

Comment: @AdminBee Good point, I meant to show just a quick example, but quoting the arguments never hurts :). Changed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't see how this script will help. If you run `mv a.txt b.txt` then `b.txt` has now been overwritten, and there's nothing that will un-overwrite it. If you mean that the user can edit the command line before running the `mv` command, then it surely would be just as easy to swap the arguments as it would to insert `un` at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @roaima Of course "reversing" the command works only when `b.txt` did not exist previously, so I assumed this is the case. If there's no command line editing, then for me the question is pointless, because if the user has to retype the entire command anyway, he can as well retype it with arguments swapped. For me, the question is meaningful only in the case when one can return to the previous command and make a small change (I don't consider swapping arguments to be "small" change). If one can add parameter `--reverse`, as the OP asked, one can also add `un` at the beginning of the command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification